# Using graph object to insert records into AP Bills and Adjustments

Tags: acumatica

I have custom code to insert records into the Bills and Adjustments for another company using a web service (a cludgey solution, I agree) that logs into another company.  This works fine - but can be a bit slow due to the number of records needing to be created.

I'm now trying to use the Bills and Adjustments graph object (APInvoiceEntry) and DACs (APInvoice and APTran) to do the same entry.  I'm running into errors that I didn't receive using the web service method.  In the interface, when you enter certain fields, others will default.  I'm wondering if the same actions occur when you use the graph to insert a record.  If not, then I'm assuming I'd have to populate every field in the DAC and not rely on the defaulting properties of the interface.  Is that a correct assumption?  The errors I'm getting don't really make much sense to me, such as:

```
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Vendor value 2359 Error: PayAccountID '1931' cannot be found in the system. Please verify whether you have proper access rights to this object.
```

Not sure why PayAccountID would be an issue, as this particular value '2359' does exist in the system...

Here's an example of what I'm currently trying to do using the graph object:

```
            APInvoiceEntry apgraph = null;
            APInvoice apinvoice = null;
            APTran aptran = null;

            //Get the dataset:
             PXResultset<xvwInterCompanyProcess> res = PXSelect<xvwInterCompanyProcess,
                                                       Where<xvwInterCompanyProcess.origRefNbr, Equal<Required<ARInvoice.refNbr>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), arinvoice.RefNbr);

            using (PXLoginScope ls = new PXLoginScope("InterCompany@Canada"))
            {
                foreach (PXResult<xvwInterCompanyProcess> rec in res)
                {

                    xvwInterCompanyProcess icp = (xvwInterCompanyProcess)rec;

                    //Save if the RefNbr has changed - unless it's the first record...
                    if (icp.OrigRefNbr != LastRefNbr)
                    {
                        //Save if it's the next header level record - but not if it's the first time through...
                        if (Counter > 0) apgraph.Persist();

                        //Create a new instance of the AP Bills screen graph..
                        apgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<APInvoiceEntry>();

                        //Create new header DAC and add the header records...
                        apinvoice = new APInvoice();
                        apinvoice.DocType = icp.DocType;  //apDocType;
                        apgraph.Document.Insert(apinvoice);

                        apinvoice.DocDate = icp.DocDate;
                        apinvoice.InvoiceNbr = icp.VendorRef;
                        apinvoice.DocDesc = icp.Description;
                        apinvoice.BranchID = 6;
                        apinvoice.CuryID = "USD";

                        //Get the Vendor ID from the Vendor CD ("ZINTERPAY")...
                        BAccount bacct = (BAccount)PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.acctCD, Equal<Constants.zinterpay>>>.Select(new PXGraph<ARDocumentRelease>());
                        apinvoice.VendorID = bacct.BAccountID;

                        //Insert the header (APInvoice) record into the AP Bills graph object..
                        apgraph.Document.Update(apinvoice);
                        apgraph.Persist();
                     }
                     //...create tran level records (code left out)
                     LastRefNbr = icp.OrigRefNbr;                        
                     Counter++;
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with a code snippet?

Comment: Done.   I didn't include the Web Service code as that works

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the error message says, that PayAccountID '1931' cannot be found in the system when the system is processing 2359 assigned to the Vendor field.

It is possible the error to be caused by 2 things:

1. the result of `apgraph.Document.Insert(apinvoice)` is not assigned back to the apinvoice variable
2. since the system will re-assign the default BranchID after VendorLocationID gets updated, you should subscribe to the APInvoice.BranchID FieldDefaulting handler in order to create an AP Invoice under specific branch

Below is the update code snippet to create AP Invoices under a specific branch:

```
var apgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<APInvoiceEntry>();
apgraph.FieldDefaulting.AddHandler<APInvoice.branchID>((s, e) =>
{
    e.NewValue = 17;
    e.Cancel = true;
});

var apinvoice = new APInvoice();
apinvoice.DocType = APDocType.Invoice;
apinvoice = apgraph.Document.Insert(apinvoice);

apinvoice.DocDate = DateTime.Now;
apinvoice.InvoiceNbr = "0!23!";
apinvoice.DocDesc = "Demo StackOverflow Bill";

BAccountR bacct = (BAccountR)PXSelect<BAccountR,
    Where<BAccountR.acctCD, Equal<Required<BAccountR.acctCD>>>>
    .Select(apgraph, "AEROCOREBE");
apinvoice.VendorID = bacct.BAccountID;

apgraph.Document.Update(apinvoice);
apgraph.Actions.PressSave();
```